# Primefaces p:draggable - how to catch event during dragging?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to catch event when after drag but before drop event.

Draggable items are in DataTable as first column, like this:

```
<p:column style="width:20px">
    <h:outputText id="pTaskDragIcon" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4" />
    <p:draggable for="pTaskDragIcon" revert="true" containment="window" />
</p:column>
```

I want to get dragged object and save it into managedbean before item was dropped. 
And I cannot even catch that event.